# How to display data to HTML using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, cordova, innerhtml

I have a problem for displaying the data to HTML using javascript. The code that i create only display the latest data instead of the whole data. I use phonegap in my development. Here is the code:

```
 var oldHtml = document.getElementById("favorite-table-id").innerHTML;

 for(var i=0; i<courseIdResult.length;i++) {
    //var idResult = courseIdResult[i];
    db.transaction(
            function(tx) {
                var query='SELECT Title,Institution_Id,FullTime,EntryScore,Prerequisites FROM Course WHERE Id='+courseIdResult[i];
                tx.executeSql(query,[],function(tx,resultSet) {
                    console.log("Test 0");
                    var row = resultSet.rows.item(0);
                    var newHTML = "<tr> <td> <table> <tr> <td width=1% style='white-space:nowrap;font-weight:bold' align='left'>" +row['Title']+"-"+row['Institution_Id'] +
                      "</td> <td align='right' style='vertical-align:middle;' rowspan=2> <a href='#'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-star'></span></a> </td></tr> <tr> <td width=1% style='white-space:nowrap'>" +
                      "Years:"+row['FullTime']+ "  ATAR:"+row['EntryScore']+ "  Prereq:"+row['Prerequisites']+ 
                      "</td> </tr> </table> </td> </tr>";
                    document.getElementById("favorite-table-id").innerHTML= oldHtml + newHTML;
                },errorCB);
            },errorCB
        );
}
```

variable courseIdResult is an ID for my query and i am using loop to get the data. However, everytime the loop progress, the value of document.getElementById("favorite-table-id").innerHTML is always overwrite. Please help me to solve this problem.

Thank you

Comment: You're setting oldHtml outside the for loop, so oldHtml is probably the empty string. You're also spawning (potentially) many queries. Try reworking the code to execute only one query, and iterate through the resultSet.

Comment: I try to execute with only one query however the database design is mess so i need twice execution to fetch the data. The first query execution resulted in comma(,) separate value: 1,2,3,4,5,6. I need to split this value to look other table in DB. I only spawn 2 queries.

Comment: do you want to fetch value like Select * From table where xxx in ('1','2')

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var q = "";
for (var i = 0; i < courseIdResult.length; i++) {
    q += (q == "" ? "" : ", ") + "?";
}
var query = 'SELECT Title,Institution_Id,FullTime,EntryScore,Prerequisites FROM Course WHERE Id IN (' + q + ')';
var db = CreateDB();
var row = '';
db.transaction(populateDB, errorDB, successDB);
function populateDB(tx) {
    tx.executeSql(query, courseIdResult, function (tx, results) {
        var len = results.rows.length;
        var arrSectionTableName = [];
        if (len > 0) {
            $("#favorite-table-id").empty();
            var newHTML = "";
            for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                 newHTML += "<tr> <td> <table> <tr> <td width=1% style='white-space:nowrap;font-weight:bold' align='left'>" +row['Title']+"-"+row['Institution_Id'] +
                  "</td> <td align='right' style='vertical-align:middle;' rowspan=2> <a href='#'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-star'></span></a> </td></tr> <tr> <td width=1% style='white-space:nowrap'>" +
                  "Years:"+row['FullTime']+ "  ATAR:"+row['EntryScore']+ "  Prereq:"+row['Prerequisites']+ 
                  "</td> </tr> </table> </td> </tr>";
            }
            $('#"favorite-table-id"').val(newHTML);
           //Refresh your control,eg if it is a listview
            $('#favorite-table-id').listview('refresh');
        }
    });
}
function errorDB(err) {
    alert("Error processing SQL " + err.message);
}
function successDB() {

}
```

Comment: The "+=" is work to display whole data however the HTML still display the latest data with many rows. How should i define the variable to make it correct ?

Answer (score 0):

append your old html to new hTML before inserting the HTML content in place holder.

```
var oldHtml = document.getElementById("favorite-table-id").innerHTML;

 for(var i=0; i<courseIdResult.length;i++) {
//var idResult = courseIdResult[i];
db.transaction(
        function(tx) {
            var query='SELECT Title,Institution_Id,FullTime,EntryScore,Prerequisites FROM Course WHERE Id='+courseIdResult[i];
            tx.executeSql(query,[],function(tx,resultSet) {
                console.log("Test 0");
                var row = resultSet.rows.item(0);
                var newHTML = oldHtml + "<tr> <td> <table> <tr> <td width=1% style='white-space:nowrap;font-weight:bold' align='left'>" +row['Title']+"-"+row['Institution_Id'] +
                  "</td> <td align='right' style='vertical-align:middle;' rowspan=2> <a href='#'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-star'></span></a> </td></tr> <tr> <td width=1% style='white-space:nowrap'>" +
                  "Years:"+row['FullTime']+ "  ATAR:"+row['EntryScore']+ "  Prereq:"+row['Prerequisites']+ 
                  "</td> </tr> </table> </td> </tr>";
                document.getElementById("favorite-table-id").innerHTML= newHTML;
            },errorCB);
        },errorCB
    );
```

}