# How to send value to div element with javascript in cordova android (sqlite)?

Tags: javascript, android, html, sqlite, cordova

I am using Phonegap sqlite.
I have one table in my database named "database" in which I have 3 columns.id,data,data_num
I wanted to fetch all data from database and show it in html div.This is what I came up with:

> **Script:**

```
<script>
      document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false); 
      function refresh() {
        var db = window.sqlitePlugin.openDatabase("Database", "1.0", "Demo", -1);
       var name=document.forms["frm1"]["name"].value;
       var id=document.forms["frm1"]["id"].value;
       var sal=document.forms["frm1"]["sal"].value;
        db.transaction(function(tx) {
              tx.executeSql("SELECT data from test_table;", [], function(tx, res) {
                 var len = results.rows.length;
                 var databit;
                    if(len>0)
                    {
                        for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) 
                        {
                            databit=results.rows.item(0)['data']);
                        }
                    }
                    document.getElementById("data").innerHTML=databit;
              });
            });

      </script>
```

> **HTML**

```
<input type="button" value="Refresh" onClick="return refresh()">
<div id="data"></div>
```

But it does'nt work as subjected.

NOTE:This is code snippet.Assume all undeclared variable as declared.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20698779/how-to-display-data-to-html-using-javascript/20698930#20698930 hope this link will help

Comment: <div id="data"></div> quotes(") was missing for div id :)

Comment: " missing isn't the problem...I have tried it with " only.It was a typo while asking. :(

Comment: this link didnt helped you?

Comment: mark that as an answer than :)